# how to sort columns in excel and calculate the sum of group data

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file that has 25 columns; A thru Y.

The first row contains headers for the columns.

I want to be able to sort, first by column X, then Y, then L, then H, and
finally I. Columns X, Y, and L contain numbers, and H and I contain letters.

After sorting I want to calculate the sum of values in columns T and U (also
contain numbers) that have the same value in column X and put the value, in
bold, after the last entry.

Like this:

before:

```
column T    column U    column X    
48300       48300       3318135
614004      623034      3319012
7163380     7284690     3319012
2046680     2076780     3319012
6140040     6230340     3319014
41342936    42043068    3319014
```

after:

```
column T    column U    column X    
48300       48300       3318135
48300       48300

614004      623034      3319012
7163380     7284690     3319012
2046680     2076780     3319012
9824064     9984504

6140040     6230340     3319014
41342936    42043068    3319014
47482976    48273408
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What you want? Do you want new sheet for result? Should we insert code for sorting? Say clearly.

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it manually and need to do the sorting repeatedly in future, you may try to use macro recorder to record your manually actions.
Call the macro when it is needed in future.

[image: Macro Recorder]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Mac so the instruction may be slightly different if you're using a PC but the principles would be the same.

To sort the data in your worksheet:

1. Select the data range you want (including header row)
2. Go to Data > Sort...
3. A window appears that allows you to select a whole range of columns to sort by (make sure you tick the "My list has headers" box). To add a new column (level) to sort by, click the + button at the bottom. Selecting ColumnX as the first level will ensure that all the rows with the same value in ColumnX will be clumped together.

To calculate the sums based on a value in another column, I'd use a Pivot table with ColumnX in the row labels and Sum of ColumnT and Sum of ColumnU in the Values box.However, if you want to set things out exactly as you've shown above you might need to do some manual editing, perhaps something like:

4. After each group (based on sorting on X, the first sort level), insert two rows.
5. Use the =sum() function in the first of the inserted rows to calculate the sum of the cells in that group. You don't need to write a =sum() function for all 25 columns. Write it for the first one and then grab the bottom right corner of the cell and drag across the row to add the same formula to each cell (adjusted for change in position).

It's not very elegant but, if it's only a single spreadsheet, it may be feasible as a one-off option.